# CSS wont sync with HTML?

Tags: html, css

This is my MyWebsite.html file

```
<DOCTYPE !html>
<html>
<head>

<title>My Website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyWebsite.css" media="screen" type="text/css">               
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="top">

<div class="panel-footer row"><!-- panel-footer -->

<div class="col-xs-6 text-left">       
      <button id="home" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><a href="#" style="color:white"> Home</a></button>   
<a href="#"> <img href="#" style="height:35px" src="https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/images/generic/en-play-badge.png"> </a>
     <a href="#"> <img href="#" style="height:35px"  src="http://www.mosa.nl/files/8613/8668/4836/available-in-app-store-badge.png">  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">   
      <button id="ourApps" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span><a href="#" style="color:white"> Our Apps</a></button>
      <button id="contactUs" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span   class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a href="#" style="color:white"> Contact   Us</a></button>
</div>
</div><!-- end panel-footer -->
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

My CSS wont really matter because I've cleared it many times because it did not work.
When I open the website in Chrome, the CSS simply does not kick in and does not take effect. For example, I would do "text-decoration: none;" for all `<a>` tags, but still, there would be an underline when I hover over the text. Or, when I try to change the text color, it still stays black. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Post the CSS in MyWebsite.css.

Comment: Go to your Developer tools and check that `MyWebsite.css` loaded properly, your probably not referencing to it correctly.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to place your own CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MyWebsite.css" media="screen" type="text/css">
```

below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The simple reason is that your CSS properties in MyWebsite.css gets overrided by the CSS properties in bootstrap.min.css file.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after that. All the CSS properties worked except for text-decoration: none;. What is the proper syntax and use for this attribute? Thanks anyways tho!

Comment: text-decoration: none|underline|overline|line-through|initial|inherit are the different properties it supports. You can also edit the bootstrap.css file if you want to use text-decoration: none; throughout the website.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, do mark it as an answer..!!!

Comment: Ha sorry I don't use the website much I don't know this stuff :p